# Is there a way to make a derived class not inherit all the members from the base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

So i'm having elipse as a base class which has as members two doubles which represent the two radiuses.
I want to derive a circle class from it. Circle needs only one radius as a member but it still inherits two from elipse. I feel like i'm wasting memory. In this particular case it's not that big of a deal but I think in other contexts it might.
p.s. elipse is also derived from a figure class which is an interface

Here are the headers of the 3 classes:

figure.h

```
 #pragma once
 #define PI 3.1415
class figure
{
public:
    virtual double area() = 0;
    virtual double perimeter() = 0;
};
```

elipse.h

```
#pragma once
#include "figure.h"

class elipse : public figure
{
protected:
    double radius1, radius2;

public:
    elipse(double radius1 = 0, double radius2 = 0);
    
    void set_radius1(double);
    void set_radius2(double);
    double get_radius1();
    double get_radius2();

    double area() override;
    double perimeter() override;
};
```

circle.h

```
#pragma once
#include "elipse.h"

class circle:
    private elipse
{
public:
    circle(double radius = 0);
    double perimeter() override;
    double area() override;

    double get_radius();
    void set_radius(double);
};
```

Here is the implementeetion of the set_radius method to show that i still need to set two radiuses even if in theory i need one.

```
void circle::set_radius(double radius)
{
    set_radius1(radius);
    set_radius2(radius);
}
```

Comment: No. If you're that concerned about the space, then inherit directly from figure.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't go the opposite way in your hierarchy. I.e. figure ==> circle ==> elipse, where you add the second radius to `elipse` rather than trying to hide an unneeded radius from `circle`

Comment: I thought about that but it doesn't really make sense because circle is a particular case of the elipse, not the other way around

Comment: @WhozCraig Inheritance typically represents "is-a" relationship. Ellipse is not a circle.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can understand it since an ellipse is not a circle

Comment: Not sure if you should make one of `circle` or `ellipse` subclasses of the other. Mathematically there may be a "is a" relationship between `circle` and`ellipse`, but in your program there isn't necessarily one: Neither`circle::get_radius()` nor`ellipse::get_radius1()`are part of both classes so none operations available for one of the types is a subset of the other.You may be better of moving the logic for calculating the derived properties to helper functions,that is if you want to share the logic at all;another option would be to allow`ellipse c = ellipse::create_circle(r);`(no type circle)

Comment: @fabian i'm not sure what you mean by helper functions exactly. Also, how would i do this 'ellipse c = ellipse::create_circle(r)' if circle is not derived from elipse?

Comment: See [Circle-ellipse_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. When you derive `circle` from `ellipse`, under the hood it's very similar to adding a member variable of type `circle` to the `ellipse`. (And you can't add half of a `circle` as a member variable either.)

A possible solution (which is not necessarily more effective) is to make an abstract class derived from `figure`, with pure virtual getters for the two radiuses, and `area()` implemented in terms of them. Then `circle` and `ellipse` could be both derived from this class, adding member variables for radiuses, setters for them, and overriding getters. Deciding what to do with `perimeter()` is left as an exercise to the reader.